# Hibernate and Oracle Pagination/ScrollableResult for 4 million result

Tags: oracle, hibernate, pagination

May I know does oracle and hibernate support effective pagination/scrolleable result?

I remember in the past many Database just load all the resultS(4million) and "scroll" the data. Has this been change in hibernate and oracle 11g?

Any document to implement a proper pagination using hibernate and oracle if the above issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination with Hibernate can be done using `Query.setFirstResult()` and `Query.setMaxResults()`. This will trigger a SQL query which looks like this (IIRC) :

```
select * from (select _this.a, _this.b from some_table _this) where rownum > ? and rownum < ?
```

And the SQL query will just return the required page of data.

If what you want to scroll through the results of a query and not load everything in a List, use `Query.scroll()`.

Comment: but when the DB process the request... will it load the 4 million records into memory and "scroll" the data?

Comment: No, it won't. This query is the best you can do to only fetch a page of data.

Comment: any reference documents? Thanks for answering my question once again, JB Nizet

Comment: reference document about what? How rownum works? Google for the oracle database documentation.